# SDL2 Side scrolling variable not accruing

Tags: c++, scroll

I have a cat game I have been working on in pygame that I am now writing in c++ SDL2 which are similar. But I have a weird specific problem. A variable in my level.cc class doesn't accrue with old += new in the move() function I am thinking that it is being set to 0 somewhere or my scope is off but I am just lost. I will post the files that are pertinent here and then link to my github as well. I appreciate your time and help.

The level.cc file:

```
void Level::move(int newx){
    groundX += newx;
}
```

and the cat.cc file:

```
void Cat::move(int screenSize, Level l){
    if((catmX + mVelX > 0) && (catmX + mVelX + (catwidth / 2) < (screenSize * .70))){
        catmX += mVelX;
    } else if(catmX + mVelX + (catwidth / 2) >= (screenSize * .70)){
        l.move(CAT_VEL);
        catmY += mVelY;
    }
}
```

and the main:

```
    string grndLoc = "src/grass.png";
    Level level1(extra.loadTexture(grndLoc, extra.getRen()), extra.getHeight());

    string backgroundImage = "src/sky.png";
    SDL_Texture *bck = extra.loadTexture(backgroundImage, extra.getRen());
    if(bck == nullptr){
        extra.destroyer(bck);
        extra.quitGame();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Event e;
    bool quit = false;

    while(!quit){
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
            if(e.type == SDL_QUIT){
                quit = true;
            }
            switch(e.key.keysym.sym){
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
            }
            catplayer.handleEvent(e);
        }
        SDL_RenderClear(extra.getRen());
        extra.renderTexture(bck, extra.getRen(), 0, 0, extra.getWidth(), extra.getHeight());
        level1.rend(extra);
        extra.renderTexture(catplayer.getTexture(), extra.getRen(), catplayer.getX(), catplayer.getY(), catplayer.getclip());
        SDL_RenderPresent(extra.getRen());
        catplayer.move(extra.getWidth(), level1);
```

https://github.com/ironsketch/catGamecpp

Comment: I would suggest you to reduce a bit the code shown to the relevant part. This is far too much to review by most people. Your chances of help will also increase a lot if you do it.

Comment: @GermánDiago Thank you!

Comment: This is an accuracy problem I am sure. How many frames per second do you have? If you increase your variable n times per second but lose a "floating point" part of the increase, this error will accumulate. I had a similar problem before. I would suggest you to try the following: use a floating point variable, accumulate there. When rendering, use the integer part of it, but leave the accumulation in the floating point variable. So for example: float x = 2.63; you render 2 units to the right and accumulate that 0.63, next frame: you have 3.5, so u render 3 and leave 0.5 for next accumulated.

Answer (score 0):

My teacher made mention that I was probably calling the constructor somewhere! I found that I was passing a copy of the level and not a pointer to the level!

```
void Cat::move(int screenSize, Level l){
```

So I changed it to

```
void Cat::move(int screenSize, Level *l){
```

I updated a few other things to reflect that I am now using a pointer and it's fixed! Thanks everyone who responded <3